# Launch a system generated application with same package name

Tags: android

I am trying to make a small application that can launch an application, not usually shown in the app drawer. This application is generated by the system and is carrier specific. It belongs to the package com.android.stk  - for those of you who don`t know it is the SIM Toolkit application. The SIM Toolkit application itself can not be launched, but when I insert my sim card, it creates a carrier specific application - In my case: Dialog Services, which can be run to make changes to sim settings.

The problem is that the package name for the Dialog Services app is still com.andorid.stk . All I want to do is open up that app. Is there any way to do this... Possibly search for all apps within com.android.stk and selecting or launching that one...

I am relatively new to Android dev, so All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch any installed application whose package name is known:

```
   Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.andorid.stk");
    startActivity( LaunchIntent );
```